# Java - Register autostart for application

Tags: java, windows, windows-8, windows-7, autostart

Is there a cross platform way to make my java application auto-start? If there is no cross platform way, is there at least a Windows 7 & Windows 8 technique?

I need to know how this is possible using java code.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For windows, create a .bat batch file and put following command

> @javaw -jar jar-path-directory arguments

put the batch file in startup directory

Comment: Where is the startup directory? And the Java-app should make itself autostart on the next system start. So does a usual Java-app have the permission to write to the startup directory? And is there a comparable way on how to do this on apple?

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup if your windows installed in C drive

Comment: Thank you. Is it the same for Windows 7? And apple?

Comment: i dont use mac so can not confirm you :)

Comment: How can I access that folder in java? The actual folder name may vary because it contains the username. And is a Java-application able to write in this location?

Comment: I just tried it out and it worked :D But I have one question: It always opens the console window. Is there a way to prevent that?